# Light fixture holes don't align with junction box

Tags: light-fixture

I bought a light fixture for my bathroom and noticed the screw holes on the fixture are in a N/S orientation, while the junction box is in an E/W orientation. I am able to rotate the existing bracket to accommodate the different orientation (the one that came with the fixture is too small), but I'm wondering if I should replace the current box with one that has a N/S orientation, or if I can screw holes through the drywall to hold the fixture. I did rotate the one piece of the bracket to go into a N/S orientation, so I could attach the fixture to that, but that part of the bracket doesn't screw into anything behind it. The fixture will go on the wall, not the ceiling.

[image: Light fixture image]

Comment: I think that fixture is missing an important piece.  Notice how the cables enter the fixture in 3 places.  You can't just shove that up against the ceiling, there needs to be some sort of enclosure to protect the 3 cables.  Was this bought off ebay/Amazon/Aliexpress? Bargain "opened box" deal?

Comment: It's on the wall, not the ceiling - I say that in the last sentence of my post.   I bought this new fixture from Lowes, unopened.

Comment: Ok nevermind, I see now the fixture has sidewalls which enclose a substantial void, the wiring goes in there.  It is rather odd that the only attachments are in the center.

Answer (score 2):

There is a round plate adapter made to give you the right orientation. Any lighting supply house can help you. Good Luck.

Comment: The thing you're looking for is called a "universal crossbar", by the way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code or rule that says you can't mount a fixture directly to the dry wall. I would use something like a 4" toggle either 1/4 or 3/8. But as @Harper has pointed out there are codes and rules about using that space for a junction area. This is one I would run by the AHJ first.